# Create column input based on string input in Python function

Tags: python, string, list, function, if-statement

So I am writing a custom function where I want a string input being transformed into a dataframe, ready for a model to do predictions on. Right now I am stuck writing a piece of code that is able to detect if the input string contains specific words and then if it does, process this to a dataframe column where the value is either 1 or 0. However, I have not been able to succesfully wright it, how can I best approach this?
This is my piece of code:

```
def function(text_input)
    cols = ['col_foo', 'col_bar', 'col_hello', 'col_world']
    words = ['foo', 'bar', 'hello', 'world']
    data = [text_input.split()]
    for col in cols:
        df[col] = 0
    for word in data:
        if word in words:
           for words in cols:
               df[cols] = 1
    return df
```

I am expecting that all cols will first be created with initial 0 values. Then based on the words in the `text_input` that match with the words in the `words` list, the corresponding `cols` will be set to 1 values. But right now, this code outputs all `df[cols] = 0`

What am I doing wrong in this piece of code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Review your code then you will see the problem.

Comment: I believe the problem is in the `for words in cols:` line. Because of the added col_ name, this does not match. How do I rewrite it so it matches just the actual name of the column part?

Comment: use used `cols` under that not `words`

Comment: Not quite sure if I get what you mean. What I am trying to do in the last part, is set the value to 1 of those columns that match with the words that match the words in the `text_input`

Comment: `df[cols]` --> `df['col_foo', 'col_bar', 'col_hello', 'col_world']`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
def text_detecter(text_input): 
     df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[0],'bar':[0],'hello':[0],'world':[0]}) 
     for col in df.columns: 
     df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: 1 if col in text_input else 0) 
     return df
```

So if you then run this:

```
text_detecter('foo')
```

It would lead to the dataframe:

```
     foo  bar  hello  world
0    1    0      0      0
```

Comment: Yes this does make a lot of sense. The only thing I want to add is to have a prefix for the col names: `col_` How do I add that? Also if it does not recognize a word in the text_input, I still want all the columns created and set to 0.

Comment: `def text_detecter(text_input): 
    df = pd.DataFrame({'col_foo':[0],'col_bar':[0],'col_hello':[0],'col_world':[0]}) 
    for col in df.columns: 
        df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: 1 if col[4:] in text_input else 0) 
    return df`

Comment: You can have them like that, just add [4:] to the col in the for loop as above.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting a KeyError: 'foo'. Not sure what is causing this, the TraceBack does not make a lot of sense, since this function is built in within a bigger function

Comment: Somewhere foo is used not as a string but as a variable (so maybe without ' ' around it) which would cause that error

Comment: Ok yeah I am trying something else where I am creating columns of the same name in a new df and then do: `for col in other_df.columns: df[col] = 1`. But then I need to create a list of the words in `text_input` for every word in `words`. With `words_text=[]   for word in words:   if word in data: words_text.append(word)` I am getting an empty list